# initialize 3D std::vector with size and value

Tags: c++, vector, std

I am having some difficulties declaring a 3D std::vector with size 200-by-200-by-200. I can see questions on SO about setting size and initialize it with a value, but all are for 1D vector.

I tried to start with something like

```
vector<vector<vector<uchar>>> vsfl(200,200,200,1);
```

but having compilation error.

I originally began with uchar vsfl[200][200][200] but resulted in stack overflow error

Thank a bunch!

Comment: go back to where you began, but move the declaration outside the function, and you won't get a stack overflow error

Comment: @zeromus: I tried what you said, but in reversed way, from a class's property to a variable within the function and there's no stack overflow error. Thank you! by the way, nested vector is a bad option?

Comment: It may be a good or bad option, it depends on what you're doing with it. For most cases the vectors will be much more slow and bloated than a simple array.

Having such a large array in a function may bite you again later in a different way, watch out. Bottom line is, you need to get it out of the stack somehow (or use vectors as you suspected, which effectively calls a bunch of new[]s secretly to avoid it being on the stack)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same thing as a 1D vector, but you have to change the parameters a bit:

```
vector<vector<vector<int>>> vsfl(200, vector<vector<int>>(200, vector<int>(200, 1)));
```

Because the `std::vector` constructor takes `T` as the second argument and it's a 3D vector, so you have to call `T`s constructor if you want to have it initialized.

Answer (score 0):

go back to where you began, but move the declaration outside the function, and you won't get a stack overflow error. That's too much memory for the stack.

If the code you're writing is in a method, then moving it outside the function will cause the object to be large--if you declare that object inside a function, you'll get the same problem. At that point, you can move the object declaration outside the function, or new it.

Another option, if you need it, would be this:

```
struct BigArray { int elems[200][200][200]; };
//be sure to delete me!
BigArray *test = new BigArray;
```

Answer (score -1):

First, select what container you want to use. If the size of *every* container is known at compile time, such as your case seems to be, and it never changes, then use plain old arrays.

Otherwise, you want a vector. What you want, in algorithmic means, is to have a vector initialized with 200 vectors initialized with 200 vectors initialized with 200 `uchar`s, whatever an `uchar` is.

So, in order to do that, you may use...

```
template<typename T>
using unidimensional_vector = std::vector<T>;

template<typename T>
using bidimensional_vector = std::vector<unidimensional_vector<T>>;

template<typename T>
using tridimensional_vector = std::vector<bidimensional_vector<T>>;

tridimensional_vector<uchar> my_vector(200, bidimensional_vector<uchar>(200, unidimensional_vector<uchar>()));
```